# Creating a Setup.exe with Mysql Installer

Tags: mysql, windows-installer, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I need to create a setup with Mysql installer included in the project, i am using visual studio 2015 and installshield 2015 LE, i need to check if there is MySql already installed if there's nothing installed, setup will install MySql and continue installing the main project. Having a hard time doing this 'cause i am only using LE version. i tried it on a Installshield Professional trial using chained MSI but it seems doesn't check if there is existing Mysql.

Any suggestions, tutorials or alternatives rather than Installshield?

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) released long time ago. You can use customized script to perform checking and installation.